# deserialization json data from wikipedia api to get the thumburl from three imageinfo

Tags: c#, json, image, deserialization, wikipedia-api

I make a request at wikipedia api to get thumburl from every imageinfo, so that I can use this picture in the picturebox. I use the url https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=400&titles=File%3ALuftbild%20Flensburg%20Schleswig-Holstein%20Zentrum%20Stadthafen%20Foto%202012%20Wolfgang%20Pehlemann%20Steinberg-Ostsee%20IMG%206187.jpg%7CFile%3AHafen%20St%20Marien%20Flensburg2007.jpg%7CFile%3ANordertor%20im%20Schnee%20(Flensburg%2C%20Januar%202014).JPG to get three image. I got following json file from json2csharp.

```
  {
    public class Imageinfo
   {
    public string thumburl { get; set; }
    public int thumbwidth { get; set; }
    public int thumbheight { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string descriptionurl { get; set; }
   }

   public class Pageval
   {
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string missing { get; set; }
    public string imagerepository { get; set; }
    public List<Imageinfo> imageinfo { get; set; }
   }


   public class Query
  {
    public Dictionary<string, Pageval> pages { get; set; }
  }

   public class RootObject
   {
    public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
    public Query query { get; set; }
   }




   class Image
   {
    public static PictureBox Image1 = new PictureBox();
    public static PictureBox Image2 = new PictureBox();
    public static PictureBox Image3 = new PictureBox();



    public static void Load_Image1()
    {
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=400&titles=File%3ALuftbild%20Flensburg%20Schleswig-Holstein%20Zentrum%20Stadthafen%20Foto%202012%20Wolfgang%20Pehlemann%20Steinberg-Ostsee%20IMG%206187.jpg%7CFile%3AHafen%20St%20Marien%20Flensburg2007.jpg%7CFile%3ANordertor%20im%20Schnee%20(Flensburg%2C%20Januar%202014).JPG");
            var response = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
            var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Pageval> entry in responseJson.query.pages)
            {
                var url = entry.Value.imageinfo.First().thumburl;
                for(int i; i<=3 ;i++)
                {

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a for loop by which I can show 3 image in 3 picturebox. but really dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your class definitions need a little refactoring :

```
  public class Imageinfo
            {
                public string thumburl { get; set; }
                public int thumbwidth { get; set; }
                public int thumbheight { get; set; }
                public string url { get; set; }
                public string descriptionurl { get; set; }
            }

            public class Pageval
            {
                public int ns { get; set; }
                public string title { get; set; }
                public string missing { get; set; }
                public string imagerepository { get; set; }
                public List<Imageinfo> imageinfo { get; set; }
            }


            public class Query
            {
                public Dictionary<string, Pageval> pages { get; set; }
            }

            public class RootObject
            {
                public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
                public Query query { get; set; }
            }


            public class Image
            {
                public static PictureBox Image1 = new PictureBox();
                public static PictureBox Image2 = new PictureBox();
                public static PictureBox Image3 = new PictureBox();             

            }
```

And the deserializing logic :

```
   using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
      {
        var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=400&titles=File%3ALuftbild%20Flensburg%20Schleswig-Holstein%20Zentrum%20Stadthafen%20Foto%202012%20Wolfgang%20Pehlemann%20Steinberg-Ostsee%20IMG%206187.jpg%7CFile%3AHafen%20St%20Marien%20Flensburg2007.jpg%7CFile%3ANordertor%20im%20Schnee%20(Flensburg%2C%20Januar%202014).JPG");
        var response = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
        var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Pageval> entry in responseJson.query.pages)
        {
        var url = entry.Value.imageinfo.First().thumburl;
        //Do something with url
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        }

   }
```

This gives the urls. Please mark up! Thanks!

Comment: I have modified my code according to your given code. But I want set 3 picture in 3 different picturebox. I am trying. but not sure actually how to run a for loop for 3 image for 3 picturebox. Thank you for your answer.@mojorisinify

Comment: You just changed the whole question. Please dont do that.
For your answer : Create a string array of length 3. And for each item in the for loop store the url in the array. And later use these values to assign to your picture box.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for changing it. @mojorisinify